# jQuery Validation Plugin: I have multiple images, and one image needs to be selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery validation plugin, but my form includes some kind of image selector, and I need it to be validated if one image is selected or not.. but i dont know if it's possible in jQuery validation plugin. Here's the snippet of code:

```
<div id="options">
    <h1>Type</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p><a href="#"><img src="../images/general/option1.png" /></a>option1</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p><a href="#"><img src="../images/general/option2.png" /></a>option2</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p><a href="#"><img src="../images/general/option3.png" /></a>option3</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p><a href="#"><img src="../images/general/option4.png" /></a>option4</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How do I validate this in jQuery validation plugin?

Comment: How is the user selecting the images?  Are you using something like jQuery UI?  Is there a class added to the image to mark it as selected?  Why do you have </a> tags but no <a> tags?

Comment: Your html is not valid. You have a closing </a> tag for each of those images but no opening <a> tag. Also what have you tried so far with your js/jquery?

Comment: oops, i mistakenly deleted the <a href="#"> tag so that the clutter of my code disappear..

Comment: @whetstone yes, that was my initial setup, i put selected class to the selected image. but i think jquery validation plugin have a better method for validating this code.

Answer (score 1):

@Kevin Lee ,  check this Jquery plugin
http://jordankasper.com/jquery/imagecheck/examples.php

you just need to apply this plugin in to radio/checkbox group (as required) and set validation "required" for the image related radio/checkbox input field . And your all code should be within the  tag i.e

```
<form id='gallery_form'>
 <label>Sea</label>
 <input type='checkbox' name='image_gallery' value='sea' />

 <label>Mountain</label>
 <input type='checkbox' name='image_gallery' value='mountain' />

 <label>Sky</label>
 <input type='checkbox' name='image_gallery' value='sky' />

 <label>Sun</label>
 <input type='checkbox' name='image_gallery' value='sun' />

</form>
```

And javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $('input[name="image_gallary"]').each(function(){
              var src=this.value;
              $(this).simpleImageCheck({
                  image: src+'.png'
                  imageChecked: src.'_selected.png'
               });

      });

     $("#gallery_form").validate();

  });
```

just to give u and idea hope this will be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the image selection as a set of radio button inputs, and use jQuery Validation to require one of them to be checked. See this site: http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/ for an example of how to use images as radio buttons.

If you want to add support for multiple selections, you can use checkboxes instead of radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to just use some custom code based on what you've said.  If you already have a limiter to ensure that there is only one image with a selected class, simply run a $(".whatever") and check if the length is equal to one.  It's only 3 lines of code.

Comment: thanks for the comment. my initial implementation was that, but i thought it would be better if i used the jquery validation plugin because my other inputs use it.